# How to make OpenFileDialog show other user's home folders

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I used OpenFileDialog which allows user to choose files from folders. However, I'm running the process under the SYSTEM account, so it only shows the SYSTEM account folder (Home, Document, Picture, etc.. ) instead of the actual user.

How can I make OpenFileDialog under a SYSTEM process to show a particular user's folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the right question is: why must run under system account?

Comment: You could try creating worker thread to handle the file dialog and use impersonation to have the other thread run in the context of the other user.

Comment: You're then crossing threads with UI controls, which is generally not a good idea, although I'd be interested in how this affects common dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using custom places, for example:

```
openDlg.CustomPlaces.Add("C:\\Users\\User");
```

You can specify a path or a GUID, with the latter this lets you add special folders, you can find a list of valid GUID [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882665(v=vs.110).aspx), however these are often account bound so won't help you in this instance.

I think you'd have to work out the user folders yourself unfortunately.

Make sure you also enable `AutoUpgradeEnabled`.

You can read more about custom places on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.customplaces(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you @Lloyd. But is there a way to make OpenFileDialog acting like a normal process (I mean just like a normal user using it..), not only limited to a few custom path?

Comment: Not easily, you could try as suggested playing around with the thread it runs on but I only see pain in that direction. Really you should just run in the context of the user you require.